# Como recargo todos los campos del EDIT FORM de FilamentPhp desde la DataBase sin apretar SAVE y sin hacer F5?

Tags: filamentphp, laravel-filament

Como recargo todos los campos del `EDIT FORM de FilamentPhp` al haber modificado el registro desde la `DataBase` ...? sin apretar `SAVE` y sin hacer `F5`?:

Tengo un `SucursalResource.php` creado utilizando `FilamentPhp` y en la zona del `(return $form)` del `resource` yo realizo un par de actualizaciones del registro en la DB en base a la lógica del negocio, usando `->afterStateUpdated(function`.

El PROBLEMA QUE TENGO es que luego de actualizar esos datos en el registro de la DB necesito que SE VEAN REFLEJADOS en el Formulario que estoy editando sin tener que apretar el boton SAVE ni hacer un F5 de la pagina.

No he hallado la manera de hacer eso ... alguna ayuda? Existe alguien que lo haya logrado/realizado por favor?

Si es posible con algun ejemplo ya que soy bastante nuevo en `Filament`. :)

Answer (score 0):

En FilamentPhp, puedes recargar los campos del formulario después de haber modificado el registro en la base de datos utilizando JavaScript. Puedes agregar un script en la vista del formulario para actualizar dinámicamente los valores de los campos.

Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo:

```php
// En tu SucursalResource.php

use Filament\Resources\Forms\Components\Text;
use Filament\Resources\Forms\Form;

class SucursalResource extends Form
{
    // ...

    public function form(Form $form)
    {
        // Configura tus campos del formulario como de costumbre

        $form->schema([
            // ...
        ]);

        // Agrega el evento afterStateUpdated para realizar acciones después de la actualización del estado
        $form->afterStateUpdated(function ($state) {
            // Realiza tus actualizaciones en la base de datos aquí
        });

        // Retorna el formulario
        return $form;
    }
}
```

En tu vista del formulario, puedes agregar un script JavaScript para actualizar los campos automáticamente después de la actualización del estado:

```html
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
            Livewire.hook('element.updating', (from, to) => {
                // Verifica si el campo que se está actualizando es uno de los que quieres recargar
                if (to.tagName === 'INPUT' && (to.type === 'text' || to.type === 'number')) {
                    // Actualiza el valor del campo con el valor actualizado desde la base de datos
                    to.value = Livewire.components[from.getAttribute('wire:id')].get('campo_en_el_formulario');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

Asegúrate de ajustar `campo_en_el_formulario` con el nombre del campo que deseas actualizar en el formulario y disfruta del [subway del día](https://subwaysuboftheday.com/subway-del-dia/). Este script escucha los eventos de Livewire y actualiza dinámicamente los campos del formulario cuando se actualiza el estado.

Comment: Liam_Lucas muchas gracias por responder.  Suponia que habia alguna manera sin utilizar javascript (no se, algo propio de filament o laravel).  Voy a realizar pruebas en base a esta info. :)